# Background Image Adjustment on Top Level Window with Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have a basic GUI that begins with a main menu of sorts. I have successfully set a background image to that menu and it also scales when I change the dimension of the GUI window.
However when I try to define some top-level windows that are opened by the sub-menu items the background image does not appear (not to mention scale).
Not sure what I'm doing wrong but I'm attaching the code I wrote along with the images of the basic GUI.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, font, messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

root = Tk()
root.title("Decoder of ultrasound images to detect colon tumors")
# Adding window icon
root.iconbitmap('afekaImage.ico')

rootWidth, rootHeight = 600, 600

screenWidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screenHeight = root.winfo_screenheight()

topLeftPosition = (screenWidth / 2 - rootWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2 - rootHeight / 2)

# Configure window size
root.geometry(f'{rootWidth}x{rootHeight}+{int(topLeftPosition[0])}+{int(topLeftPosition[1])}')


'''
# Create username & password entry
def entryDialog():
    userName = entry1.get()
    password = entry2.get()
    if ((userName == 'Itzhak.Mamistvalov' and  password == '311396832') or
            (userName == 'AssafHasky' and password == '308333533')):
        messagebox.showinfo('info', 'Correct Login')
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('info', 'Invalid Login') '''


# open doc file
def openDocFile():
    os.startfile("mid_sub.docx")


# adjusting background image to fit window
def adjustBackgroundImage(event):
    # avoid garbage collection option 1
    # global resizedBackgroundImage, newBackgroundImage
    # ----------
    width = event.width
    height = event.height
    resizedBackgroundImage = copyImage.resize((width, height))
    newBackgroundImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resizedBackgroundImage)
    label.config(image=newBackgroundImage)
    # avoid garbage collection option 2
    label.image = newBackgroundImage
    # ----------


def createUserManualWindow(button_userManual):
    global image1
    userManualWindow = Toplevel(root)

    def activateButtonUserManual():
        button_userManual.configure(state="normal")
        userManualWindow.destroy()

    button_userManual.configure(state="disabled")
    button_exit_userManualWindow = Button(userManualWindow, text="Exit", font=fontStyle,
                                          command=lambda: [userManualWindow.destroy(), activateButtonUserManual()])
    button_exit_userManualWindow.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.8, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.1)
    # will occurs only when esc pressed
    userManualWindow.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", activateButtonUserManual)
    # ----------
    userManualWindow.geometry(f'{rootWidth}x{rootHeight}+{int(topLeftPosition[0])}+{int(topLeftPosition[1])}')
    userManualWindow.iconbitmap('afekaImage.ico')
    image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('background.jpg'))
    label1 = ttk.Label(userManualWindow, image=image1).pack()
    label1.bind('<Configure>', adjustBackgroundImage)
    label1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

def createOverviewWindow(button_userManual):
    overviewWindow = Toplevel(root)

    def activateButtonOverview():
        button_userManual.configure(state="normal")
        overviewWindow.destroy()

    button_userManual.configure(state="disabled")
    button_exit_OverviewWindow = Button(overviewWindow, text="Exit", font=fontStyle,
                                          command=lambda: [overviewWindow.destroy(), activateButtonOverview()])
    button_exit_OverviewWindow.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.8, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.1)
    # will occurs only when esc pressed
    overviewWindow.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", activateButtonOverview)
    # ----------
    overviewWindow.geometry(f'{rootWidth}x{rootHeight}+{int(topLeftPosition[0])}+{int(topLeftPosition[1])}')
    overviewWindow.iconbitmap('afekaImage.ico')


# Define background image
image = Image.open('background.jpg')
copyImage = image.copy()
backgroundImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = ttk.Label(root, image=backgroundImage)
label.bind('<Configure>', adjustBackgroundImage)
label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

# Configure font
fontStyle = font.Font(family="Segoe Script", size=10, weight=font.BOLD)

# Create buttons
button_userManual = Button(root, text="USER MANUAL", command=lambda: createUserManualWindow(button_userManual), font=fontStyle)
button_userManual.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.2, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.1)

button_overview = Button(root, text="OVERVIEW", command=lambda: createOverviewWindow(button_overview), font=fontStyle)
button_overview.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.4, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.1)

button_openDocFile = Button(root, text="DOC FILE", font=fontStyle, command=openDocFile)
button_openDocFile.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.6, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.1)

button_quit = Button(root, text="Exit", font=fontStyle, command=root.destroy)
button_quit.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.8, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.1)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: You did not put any image in the `Toplevel` window.

Comment: I've tried to but it shows an error. My question is how to do so correctly

Comment: Then show what you have tried and the full traceback of the error.

Comment: edited the code and the image with traceback of the error.
the edited part is in createUserManualWindow function.
I'm actually want the background image to fill the entire topLevel window, and use the adjustBackgroudndImage to the topLevel window also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `label1 = ttk.Label(userManualWindow, image=image1).pack()` should be changed to:

```py
label1 = ttk.Label(userManualWindow, image=image1)
label1.pack()
```

2. You should call `label1.pack()` before placing the "Exit" button, otherwise it will overlap/hide the "Exit" button.  Or call `label1.lower()` after `label1.pack()`.
3. `label` is used inside `adjustBackgroundImage()`, so even though you bind `<configure>` on `label1` to `adjustBackgroundImage()`, it would not resize image shown by `label1`.  Use `event.widget` instead of `label` inside `adjustBackgroundImage()`:

```py
def adjustBackgroundImage(event):
    label = event.widget
    # avoid garbage collection option 1
    # global resizedBackgroundImage, newBackgroundImage
    # ----------
    width = event.width
    height = event.height
    resizedBackgroundImage = copyImage.resize((width, height))
    newBackgroundImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resizedBackgroundImage)
    label.config(image=newBackgroundImage)
    # avoid garbage collection option 2
    label.image = newBackgroundImage
    # ----------
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer!